# Percentile(0.25) = Percentile(0.5) = Percentile(0.75) What I wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to ge percentile of values in each `import_count_index`

```
FORMAT(PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY `VALUE_`) OVER (PARTITION BY`IMPORT_COUNT_INDEX`) ,1)AS MEDIAN 

FORMAT(PERCENTILE_DISC(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY `VALUE_`) OVER (PARTITION BY `IMPORT_COUNT_INDEX`) ,1)AS PCT25

FORMAT(PERCENTILE_DISC(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY `VALUE_`) OVER (PARTITION BY `IMPORT_COUNT_INDEX`) ,1)AS PCT75 

FROM `rs_pre_calibration` WHERE (`RESULT_ID` = 2008) AND `JOB_NO`= 'EXF0974' AND `MC_NO` = 'BP44' AND (`TEST_DATE` BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2019-02-08')

GROUP BY `JOB_NO`,`MC_NO`,`TEST_DATE`,`TEST_TIME` ORDER BY`AUTOINDEX`
```

DATA
[image]

Comment: You just have lots of duplicate values . . . or perhaps your partition groups are too small.

Comment: For the following set: `{42}` all percentiles are the same and equal to `42`

Comment: Min 219 Max 223 but my percentiles are 220.4.

Comment: @zerkms I dont understand. Do you mind to explain more?

Comment: My data has 30 points

Comment: Without exact data it's impossible to tell why it happens exactly. It's either your window function selects not what you expect; or your data is not what you think it is.

Comment: @zerkms I JUST ADD THE DATA PLEASE HELP

Comment: @GordonLinoff please help

Comment: Why do you delect you suggestion??@zerkms

Comment: Please [reproduce your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ and add a link to it in your question so we have an executable example we can examine and use to understand the issue and give you a solution.